# jQuery "get" not loading content completely

Tags: google-chrome, jquery, jquery-get

I have my main file loading a second php file like this:

```
$.get('single.php?admin=1&start=1').success(function(data) {
    $('.loader').fadeOut(400, function() {
       $('#overlay').html(data);
       $(".content h2").css({"padding-top": "50px"});
    }); 
});
```

The overlay is filled with the content from the "single.php" page, when I view the HTML with the Chrome dev tools. And I can see the menu at the top of the page, but the main content doesn't show. When I load the page manually (http://bit.ly/1dCHTEp) the content loads every time perfectly.

Here is the page where the problem exists:

http://bit.ly/11U9OzC

Try clicking on the "expand" icon in the bottom right of any of the house divs, and you'll see the problem. If you click on the next arrow, in the top menu, it will load the 2nd div ok, and you can go back to the first div too.

This problem exists in Chrome (and also on my iPhone), not in Firefox (FF seems to work properly) and there are no errors in the dev console in Chrome. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9007140/jquery-overlay-in-chrome-safari-webkit-unable-to-make-changes may be relevant

Comment: Your style rule for ".js .bb-item" has a display:none rule applied. If I disable that style, the content shows. Maybe that is the problem?

Comment: Great spot aowie, when I set disable display:none it does indeed show.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked out your site, and looking at the HTML - all the content IS THERE, it is just hidden (it has CSS set to display:none). I suspect whatever plugin/library/whatever you're using is setting it to display:none when you don't intend it to.

Comment: You are right, I can see a display:none on item1. I can manually set the display value of item1 for now, until I can figure out why it's being set to "none". Thank you!